# Binding a name to a value vs. assigning a value to a variable

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Reading through Bartosz Milewski's piece at [fpcomplete](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/3-pure-functions-laziness-io) where he writes, `"In Haskell you never assign to a variable, instead you bind a name to a value."`

Could someone explain to me what this means, as well as the practical ramifications of this in the functional programming world?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In some sense, the only real difference is that variables in imperative languages can change whereas bound names in functional languages can't. But I think it's important to understand the higher-level semantic distinction between the two and how we *think* about them differently.

In imperative languages, a variable is a thing on its own which happens to include a value. They're often compared to boxes that contain something. The contents of a box can change and, semantically, the box has an identity of its own.

Haskell names, on the other hand, are just labels for a value. You can use one or the other completely interchangeably. Crucially, *they can't change*.

Compare binding in Haskell to function names in languages like Java¹. These can't change either, and you don't think of them on their own; they're just names for the method they're attached to.

Here's a contrived example of the difference: imagine a function `f` that closes over an imperative variable `x`:

```
var x = 7;
function foo() {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Effectively, `x` is just a name for `7`... until `x` changes. What you've closed over is the *variable* `x`, not its value `7`, so if it changes so will the behavior of `foo`.

In Haskell, on the other hand, if you bind `7` to the name `x` and close over it, that's the same as just closing over `7`.

```
let x = 7 in \ () -> x
```

does the same thing as

```
\ () -> 7
```

(which, itself, doesn't do anything more than just `7` by itself, ignoring strictness issues).

¹ ignoring reflection and similar shenanigans

Comment: Scheme is generally considered a functional language, and its variables can change.

Comment: The imperative closure example is a bit subtle. In some languages (e.g. C++) the closure on `x` could happen by value (the value of `x` is copied) or by reference (as in your example). In the first case changing `x` does not affect `foo`.

Comment: I usually think of the difference as "assigning a value to a variable" (variable named 'x', thy value shall now be 7) versus "assigning a name to a value" (7, thou shalt henceforth also be known as 'x').

Comment: @newacct: That's more a matter of the fact that "functional" is an ill-defined term more than anything. Scheme with `set!` isn't fundamentally any more functional than JavaScript, except it has some features to *encourage* programming in a functional style.